# Как подключить телефон к компьютеру через приложение?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сокет

Я подключил телефон и компьютер через библиотеку socket и termux, но при запуске у меня открывается консоль для получения данных. А как сделать приложение на которое будет перенаправлен клиент? К примеру перевести на сайт или типа того.

код сервера:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[-1][-1],1234))
server.listen()

while True:
    user, adres = server.accept()
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').lower()
        print(data)
```

код клиента:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятно что конкретно вы хотите. Что значит «перевести на сайт», зачем кого-то куда-то переводить, что мешает открыть сайт напрямую без python? Вообще, на уровне сокетов не существует понятия «сайт», в сокетах есть только байты, адреса и порты (да и то не всегда)

Comment: сделать локальный сайт на Flask как пример, просто видел подобное у ютубера

Comment: Просто убедитесь, что Flask прослушивает правильный сетевой интерфейс (или 0.0.0.0 чтобы прослушивать все интерфейсы) и просто открывайте его в браузере на телефоне по ip-адресу наподобие `http://192.168.0.179:5000`, никакие питоны с сокетами для этого не нужны

Comment: а если мне нужно получить данные с телефона? Этот способ подойдёт?

Comment: В каком смысле получить, куда получить, какие данные?

Comment: с телефона на компьютер, к примеру строку, которую написали на телефоне

Comment: Ну просто строку можно и через сокеты передавать, если хотите

Comment: а вы не знаете где найти примеры подобного?

Comment: Так вы же сами в своём вопросе написали готовый пример, занимающийся передачей строк. С ним что-то не так?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю как это обернуть в Flask, поскольку я хочу что бы это не выглядело как консоль, а как красивое приложение. К тому же я хочу добавить кнопки.

Comment: Ну тогда просто сделайте самый обычный Flask-сайт и просто открывайте его на телефоне в самом обычном браузере. Литературы по фласку в интернете навалом

Comment: Спасибо большое