# Как зайти с телефона на локальный сайт Flask?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, локальная-сеть

Я пытаюсь зайти на сайт с телефона. Если я захожу со свое компьютера по IP,который предлагают, то я попадаю на сайт вот пример рабочего IP на компьютере - http://127.0.0.1:80. Но когда я в браузере телефона пишу ту же ссылку, она не переводит меня на сайт. Всё объединено одним Wi-Fi. Перепробовал много вариантов - в том числе использование IPv4-адрес. Я хочу сделать сайт с кнопками и т.д для управления компьютером. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: 127... это типа адрес-самого-себя. На коме - это комп. На телефоне - это сам телефон. Пробовали ли IP адрес компьютера в вашей локальной сети? Скорее всего он выглядит как 192.168... И посмотреть его можно в настройках сети. И что вы имели ввиду под "использование IPv4-адрес" и "много вариантов"?

Comment: Вы же уже и так знаете IP-адрес своего компьютера, вы в предыдущем вопросе его уже использовали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1439726

Comment: mrEvgenX, я пробовал IP в формате - http://192.168..., а IPv4-адрес - это адрес, который можно найти в консоли вписав команду ipconfig

Comment: andreymal, но я хочу открыть именно сайт, а насколько мне известно - через сокет это не делается.

Comment: @anonimus все сайты всегда открываются именно через сокет, других способов в принципе не существует. Любой браузер использует сокеты, любой сервер использует сокеты, Flask тоже использует сокеты

Comment: а есть примеры как объединить телефон и компьютер?

Comment: @anonimus вы же уже и так их успешно объединили в предыдущем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1439726